# Restore data to android

Tags: data-recovery

I Backed up my data on Google, as instructed by a Samsung representative, then reset my, as instructed by same. He never told me how to recover the data. After being disconnected, during reset, he never got back in contact with me. I did all the recaver methods that are listed here. I also contacted Google, a week ago, no reply

Comment: Thing with the Google Backup is: The backup always works – which cannot be said about the restore. The latter sometimes works, sometimes is incomplete, and other times fails completely. The user has not much control; restore should kick in when you setup your Google account and check the box to (backup and) restore your data. If it does not then, it neither won't later.

Answer (score 0):

Usually with the backup it will save things like your contacts, messages, photos remotely. It can save apps data also like settings and files but not all apps utilise this and you could potentially be left not backup up.

These are usually synced from the settings / accounts / google and each one can be toggled.

[image]

What data exactly was it that you got instructed to backup ?